# External Hard disk 500 GB free but can't copy 8 GB data

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

I have WD external hard disk, which was working fine. Its MS-DOS formatted. I have downloaded a file in .mkv, which works fine, and isn't corrupted. Upon copying the 8 gb file, it says "The file is too big to be copied", whereas its only 8 GB being copied on 500GB disk. I tried formatting it. still nothing. What else can i do?

Comment: Your error is slightly different than [the error here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83477/error-copying-large-file-to-usb-16gb-thumbdrive). Glad this was sorted rapidly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The HDD is formatted using FAT32 which has a known limitation of 4GB file size. You need to format it using exFAT which is supported by OS X and Windows.